# Does the javadoc tool recognize comments inside methods?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have written a lot of comments inside my business logic like that:

```
/**
 * Do some important stuff.
 * @param pDog
 * @param pAllDogTraining
 * @return
 */
@Overwrite
public Map<DogId, Dog> doEvaluateAllDog(final Dog pDog, final Collection<DogTraining> pAllDogTraining) {
final Map<DogId, Dog> lAllDogBad = new HashMap<DogId, Dog>();
final List<DogTraining> lAllDogTraining = new ArrayList<DogTraining>(pAllDogTraining);

/**
 * Remove deleted entries.
 * Detailed description
 */
removeDeletetTrainings(lAllDogTraining);

/**
 * Set the priority for each training
 *  - bad dogs
 *  - nice dogs
 *  - unknown dogs
 * Detailed description
 */
Collections.sort(lAllDogTraining, new DogTrainingComparator());

// Iterate over training elements and set the conflict state
for(.....
```

My question is, does the `javadoc` tool recognize the doc comments inside my method blocks too? In the near future we will offer a technical documentation and the JavaDoc of our project will be part of it.

Comment: Comments inside a method usually document implementation details. A JavaDoc should describe the interface (API) of the class/method. So it's two separate things that should not be mixed anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> does the `javadoc` tool recognize the doc comments inside my method blocks too?

No.

A JavaDoc comment is a multi-line comment starting with `/**` that immediately precedes a class declaration or a method or attribute of the class.